# in R: execute function on dataframes whose names are in list

Tags: r, environment-variables

My global environment contains several dataframes. I want to execute functions on only those that contain a specific string in their name. So, I first create a list of these dataframes of interest:

```
dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']
dfs <- as.data.frame(dfs)
dfs_lst <- agrep("stats", dfs$dfs, ignore.case=FALSE, value=TRUE, 
    max.distance=0.1, useBytes=FALSE)
```

dfs_lst correctly returns all dataframes in my global environment containing the string "stats". dfs_lst

```
chr [1:3] "stats1" "stats2" "stats3".
```

Now, I want to execute functions on these 3 dataframes, however I do not know how to call them from the dfs_lst. I want something of the kind:

```
for(i in 1:length(dfs_lst){
   # Find dataframe name in dfs_lst, and then use the matching dataframe in
   # global environment. So, something of the sort:
   for(dfs_lst[i] in ls()){
        result[i,] <- dfs_lst[i] %>% 
                                 summarise(. , <summarise stuff> )
   }
}
```

For example, for i=1, dfs_lst[1] is dataframe "stats1", I would want to perform the following, and save it in the first row of "results":

```
   for(stats1 in ls()){
        result[1,] <- stats1 %>% summarise(. , <summarise stuff> )
   }
```

Comment: You should store such data.frames in a list. Then you wouldn't have such problems. See the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207) for examples and details. It seems weird at first, but makes many operations much easier.

Comment: If you already have the names of your target objects, you can just do something like `lapply(mget(dfs[,1], envir = .GlobalEnv), function(x) { ... })`.

Comment: In a pinch there's always `substitute(x, list(x = dfs_lst[1])` or `eval(parse(text = dfs_lst[1]))`, but putting them in a list is a better option before you resort to such shenanigans. [Some sort-of related reading.](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

Answer (score 3):

As @lmo pointed out, it's probably best to store these `data.frame`s together in a single `list`. Instead of having `data.frame` objects called "stats1", "stats2", etc, floating around in your environment, a (hacky) way to store all your `data.frame` objects in a `list` is this:

```
dfs <- ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) class(get(x))) == 'data.frame']

##make an empty list
my_list <- list()
##populate the list
for (dfm_name in dfs) {
   my_list[[dfm_name]] <- get(dfm_name)
}
```

Now you've got a list `my_list` containing every object of the class `data.frame` in your environment. This will probably be helpful when you want to work with all `data.frame`s names "statsX":

```
##find all list objects whose name starts with "stats"
stats_objects <- substr(names(my_list),1,5)=="stats"
results <- matrix(NA, ncol = your_length, nrow = sum(stats_objects))
##now perform intended operations
for ( row_num in 1:nrow(results)) {
  results[i,] <- my_list[stats_objects][[row_num]] %>% 
                             summarise(. , <summarise stuff> )
}
```

This should perform as necessary, after a couple alterations in the code (e.g. `your_length` needs to be specified, and you wanted all objects whose name contains "stats" so you'll need to work with regularized expressions).

What's nice about this is `my_list` contains all the `data.frames`, so if you choose to run analysis on `data.frames` not named "stats" you can still access them with a similar procedure. Hope this helps.

Comment: This can be a bit more cleanly with `apropos` and `mget`; something like `lapply(Filter(is.data.frame, mget(apropos("stats", mode = "list"), .GlobalEnv)), function (x) { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, if we have a list of interesting data frames, it will be easier to deal with the elements as data frame. So, the main issue here seems to be having just the object names and not the actual data.frame objects.

In order to follow the code and tracking the data types, I have decomposed it first:

1.

```
    env.list <- ls() # chr vector
```

2.

```
    env.classes <- sapply(env.list, function(x) class(get(x))) 
    # list of chr (containing classes), element names: data frame names
```

3.

```
   dfs <- env.list[env.classes == 'data.frame'] # chr vector
```

4.

```
    dfs <- as.data.frame(dfs) 
    # data frame with one column (named "dfs"), containing data.frame names
```

Now, we can get the list of data.frames:

3.

```
   dfs <- env.list[env.classes == 'data.frame'] # chr vector
   dfs.list <- sapply(dfs, function(x) {get(x)})
```

`grep` can be applied now to `names(dfs.list)` to get the interesting data frames.